# Apply Custom Function and write to CSV every N rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and am trying to apply a custom function to one of the columns. However, as the function is a GET request to a website, it is rather slow, and the apply function breaks after an hour or so.

As such, my current thinking is to break the dataframe up into subsamples of N rows each, apply the custom function, and appending the results to a csv. I'd like to know the most ideal way to perform this, especially on the portion of iterating N rows and saving to csv every N rows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open only a chunk of the dataframe at a time with the following :

```
for chunk in pd.read_excel(your_file, chunksize=number_of_rows_at_a_time):
    chunk
    # chunk is a sub dataframe containing chunksize number of rows
```

Though, the best option is still to find a way to not use an apply function as it is rather slow for big dataframes. I would suggest to try to find another solution if it is ever possible instead of opening chunks.

Comment: Is there a way to apply the chunk function on an existing dataframe? As my dataframe has already been filtered down from the original one imported.